# how to change the lock screen clock style?

Tags: lock-screens, htc-dream, clock

I know we have "LockBot" and "WidgetLock" to change the style of the lock screen. But they are not **free** and it seems they do not allow me to change the clock styles either. I do want to change the lock screen style, only the clock style on the lock screen. Do we have apps like this?

P.S. my Android phone is HTC G1, with CM6 mod; and I expect the clock on my lock screen looks [like this](http://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=http://modmyi.com/forums/attachments/skinning-themes-discussion/371262d1249739052-htc-hero-theme-photo.jpg&imgrefurl=http://modmyi.com/forums/skinning-themes-discussion/652531-htc-hero-theme-10.html&usg=__zAkkGYIfzLhw7YfQ-sX_30Ob0x4=&h=480&w=320&sz=47&hl=en&start=0&sig2=-mHiZrVMhTVLKHYsR2ijQQ&zoom=1&tbnid=bhkzpPMkdiDZuM%3a&tbnh=143&tbnw=106&ei=CQNiTfq5OoHCcen5qMMJ&prev=/images%3Fq%3Dhtc%2Bhero%2Block%2Bscreen%26hl%3Den%26sa%3DX%26biw%3D1280%26bih%3D963%26tbs%3Disch:1%26prmd%3Divns0%2C300&itbs=1&iact=hc&vpx=242&vpy=438&dur=2832&hovh=275&hovw=183&tx=101&ty=166&oei=KQJiTcryIsbQrQf007SqAQ&page=1&ndsp=39&ved=1t:429,r:33,s:0&biw=1280&bih=963).

Comment: Please do not use URL shorteners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a rooted phone which I assume you do since you're on CM6, [see this post](http://www.androidpolice.com/2010/11/05/how-to-replace-the-lockscreen-clock-font/) detailing how to change the font of the clock on the lock screen.

Basically you need to replace **Clocktopia.ttf** in the /system/fonts folder with your desired TTF font (remember to rename new font as Clocktopia.ttf) and reset permissions to be similar to the old file.

If you're willing to use WidgetLocker, there's the freeware [Make Your Clock Widget Beta](http://www.appbrain.com/app/make-your-clock-widget-beta/net.hubalek.android.makeyourclock) - that will, as the name suggests, allow a user to customise and create a clock widget as per your taste. You can then use this custom created widget in conjunction with WidgetLocker.

Comment: that post only teach me how to change the clock font, not the style. i want my clock style change to something like this: http://goo.gl/9HNJO

Comment: You can create a flip-style widget and then use WidgetLocker. I don't know of a freeware solution to do the same.

Comment: @davidshen84: please do not use URL shorteners on this site